# Как можно реализовать общение между java и php?

Tags: php, java

Я знаю php, мой друг изучает java, мы хотели бы сделать общение между php и java, но не знаем как, хотелось бы передавать переменные, массивы, чтобы php читал данные с mysql, давал результат java, при этом в php у меня есть только все стандартное, хостинг бесплатный не позволяет ставить дополнения к php. Версии php от 5.5 до 7.1 могу менять

Comment: данные в формате json/xml передавать например.

Answer (score 6):

Самый простой вариант - преобразовать ваши данные в формат JSON и передавать их  POST запросами.

Comment: Если не трудно, привидите пример.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим есть **PHP** скрипт по адрессу http://site1.com/some-json.php

```
<?php //some-json.php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array('field1'=>1, 'field2'=>2));
  // отдаёт json вида {"field1":1,"field2":2}
```

на стороне **Java**:

```
// https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html
URL url = new URL("http://site1.com/some-json.php");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(
    url.openStream()
  )
);
StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  json.append(line);
}
reader.close();
// далее парсим json
```